# Failed to send email using codeigniter and phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, codeigniter-3

I want to try to send an email using phpmailer in the codeigniter 3 framework, after I tested it on localhost the email was sent successfully, but when I try to run it on the hosting server an error message appears

[image: Error output]

Then I try to check my code, everything is normal, there is no difference, here is my code :

application/config/email.php

[image: Settings]

application/controller/Email.php

[image: Code]

I hope someone can help me here,

Thank you

Comment: "Failed to authenticate password". Have you checked same password via browser first?  Mainly looks like you have a problem there.

Comment: This exact problem is covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps). Please [search before you post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphpmailer%5D+Please+log+in+via+your+web+browser+and+then+try+again) as this exact question has been asked and answered many times before.